# Remove or replace till first occurence of a character in perl

Tags: perl

My program contains a string like

```
$abc= "mojo logo sfdgsdj2123 *** mojo **";
```

I want to change it to

```
$abc= "mojo *** mojo **";
```

How can i do this?

Also the characters between "logo" and the first " * " can be anything other than " * " (ie not necessarily sfdgsd2123).

So basically the question is to remove till the first occurrence of "*" after first "mojo".

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the "here's how you would do it answer" rather than write the substitution code, as you did ask "How can I do this?"

So here's how:

1. Make the regex for "a sequence of zero or more non-asterisk characters that are preceded by the word mojo"
2. Substitute the first occurrence of the substring that matches that regex with the empty string.

That's all there is to it.  It's a little one-liner in Perl and most languages with sophisticated enough regex engines to support positive lookbehind.

If all that sounded crazy, feel free to walk through the string character by character.  Find where "mojo" appears first.  Then continue walking through the string, removing all the non-asterisk characters you encounter.

Comment: I think this works. Though i tested only few cases of what can be in between mojo and *.

    $abc =~ s/mojo([^*]*)/mojo /;

Please do tell if you have a better answer

Comment: Heh, that's actually better than what I had in mind.  I was thinking  `s/(?<=mojo)[^*]*//`  which replaces the string of non-asterisks that are preceded by `mojo`.  Obviously putting `mojo` back in the replacement text is a great idea, in fact [it is shown exactly like this in this Perl Monks page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444).

Comment: @RoyOneMillion - Another option is to use the `\K`eep notation (Perl 5.10+) to preserve what you're matching to the left of it.  For example: `s/mojo \K[^*]+//` will produce your desired results.